# How can I hide a tableView when I drag it down to a certain point, Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a **textField** and when I tap it a **tableView** appear below. When I scroll the **tableView** down, say 25% of the height of the **tableView** I want to hide it. Is it possible ? I am using the **scrollViewWillBeginDragging** function but its not what I want.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview!)
    if translation.y > 550 {
        self.animateTableView(shouldShow: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this UIScrollViewDelegate method:-

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let bottomEdge: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height
    let contentSize = scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.25
    if bottomEdge >= contentSize {

        /* Code to hide tableView */
    }

}
```

Comment: nope, not working as intended. The **tableView** disappear almost immediately when I scroll it down.

Comment: That depends on the content of your tableview corresponding to the tableview frame height. Say you have 30 cells and only 4 cells visible at a time, then you will see this method works, because you have to scroll a while to reach the 25% of the content size